# How is (male) falsetto taught?

Tags: voice, teaching, voice-training, falsetto

I've encountered men and boys who are seemingly unable to sing in falsetto. They sing as high as their chest voice will allow, straining at the top, but are unable to slip into falsetto.

Presuming this isn't a physiological impossibility for them, how would a voice teacher approach teaching falsetto to them?

I've framed the question around male voices, because I'm allowing that men and women are trained differently, and my particular encounters with this limitation has only involved male voices. However, there's no reason answers can't address both.

Comment: idk… though for 30 years of my life I had just that… 3 ½ octaves of 'full voice' but am incapable of singing any higher by switching to falsetto. I *can* sing falsetto, just with the same limits. [I've now lost a lot of the top end, but the limitation remains]

Comment: Were they trained in any kind of singing before?  Do they have a cultural/psychological aversion to singing in that register?

Comment: @Theodore good questions. No and no.

Comment: Very interesting, but IMO phrased a bit broadly. What would you like to know specifically about how male falsetto is taught?

Comment: @user45266 I don't know how to answer that. I'm wondering how a voice teacher would approach a student who is seemingly unable to produce a falsetto tone and can sing only in chest voice.

Comment: Oh, you mean "how would a voice teacher teach it to *those* men and boys", right?

Comment: @user45266 Yes. That's what I was trying to get at.

Comment: Why specifically male? Do you think women all magically know how to switch and never need to learn it?

Comment: @Divizna - The general vibe I've read is that women's voice ranges tend to go high enough that falsetto isn't necessary (and sounds terrible in some soprano roles like *The Phantom of the Opera*'s Christine).

Comment: @Divizna It's because I'm allowing that men and women are taught differently. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I teach kids from age 3-4 through to age 12, or early childhood up until/into voice change at puberty.  I've noticed anecdotally that ... (1) those boys who can be encouraged to sing in their head voice before puberty have a much easier time singing in head voice or falsetto once their voce changes, and (2) many boys in America naturally avoid singing in their upper registers to avoid sounding "like a girl."  So while I don't have an answer for how to teach a post-pubescent boy or adult to access these registers, I do think that good training before puberty can make a difference.

Comment: But... if you listen to pop music, both present and older, both male and female singers use head voice _a lot_! Anyway, question to OP, are you asking about falsetto specifically, or about head voice too? I know (some people claim that) there is a difference between the two, but I fail to understand it.

Comment: @user1079505 I'm specifically asking about falsetto. My understanding of the difference is that it has to do with how strong the vocal cord vibrations are. But if teaching one teachers the other, then a discussion of teaching head voice would work for my purposes.

Comment: "presuming this isn't a physical impossibility..."   I rather doubt it's even mildly difficult for those able to hit falsetto to start doing so.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Then why haven't they?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Well I sure do have to switch if I want to sing along to [No More Lonely Nights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-T_ZkacL9A0). Granted, I've never been trained (and I'm far from a soprano)... But, I've read that (male, of course) theoreticists long thought that female falsetto doesn't exist because they couldn't hear a difference in timber and so they claimed that women are incapable of it but have much larger normal voice range instead. Which is a load of bwahaha what.

Comment: @Divizna - I've also read that females sing in head voice significantly more easily than males because the head voice transition is at around the E to F above Middle C. (If head voice truly means "no more chest vibrations", this seems about right for my voice.)

Answer (score 2):

Trying to describe any vocal 'process' can be very difficult, and often ends up by using nebulous instructions like "sing through the top of your head".

Teaching by example is often more beneficial than descriptions. Show them how you do it. Try to find some exercise that enables falsetto.

Falsetto can require more diaphragm pressure and breath control -- novices often complain that they can't sing as long phrases as with their chest voice; so it can indeed be more difficult, physically.

A first approach is to ask them to mimic yodelling: sing a low note and try to 'flip it' to a high one, without sliding.

Many people find their falsetto as a more relaxed method of singing higher notes, so encouragement to relax into it may help. Short repeated percussive 'ahs' at a high pitch may be a way to feel different ways of making the sound.